# Project Euler # 11, variables overflowing

Tags: c++

Trying to solve project euler #11 and I keep getting a negative number for the two biggest products I'm outputting. Sort of at my wits end, and I figured by using long long data type I'd be safe, but I have no idea what is going on. I don't know what else to try, I'm probably doing something very silly but I've been spinning my wheels in the sand for a few hours and it's time to reach out I think

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

long long hZ (int matrix[20][20], int i, int j);

int main()
{
    fstream inFile;
    int matrix [20][20];
    long long max = 0;
    inFile.open("numbers.txt");
    if(!inFile)
        cout << "numbers.txt failed to open!" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            inFile >> matrix[i][j];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            long long temp = hZ(matrix, i, j);
            if (temp > max)
                max = temp;
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " " << matrix[i][j+1] << " " << matrix[i][j+2] << " " << matrix[i][j+3] << " " << matrix[i][j+4];
            //cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout << " product: " << temp << " max: " << max << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "The max is: " << max;
    return 0;
}

long long hZ (int matrix[20][20], int i , int j)
{
        long long hZ_product = 0;
        hZ_product = (matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j+1] * matrix[i][j+2] * matrix[i][j+3] * matrix[i][j+4]);

    return hZ_product;
}
```

OUTPUT: (if you scroll down on the output to nearly the end you will see where I commented on the lines that are causing issues):

```
8 2 22 97 38 product: 1297472 max: 1297472
2 22 97 38 15 product: 2432760 max: 2432760
22 97 38 15 0 product: 0 max: 2432760
97 38 15 0 40 product: 0 max: 2432760
38 15 0 40 0 product: 0 max: 2432760
15 0 40 0 75 product: 0 max: 2432760
0 40 0 75 4 product: 0 max: 2432760
40 0 75 4 5 product: 0 max: 2432760
0 75 4 5 7 product: 0 max: 2432760
75 4 5 7 78 product: 819000 max: 2432760
4 5 7 78 52 product: 567840 max: 2432760
5 7 78 52 12 product: 1703520 max: 2432760
7 78 52 12 50 product: 17035200 max: 17035200
78 52 12 50 77 product: 187387200 max: 187387200
52 12 50 77 91 product: 218618400 max: 218618400
12 50 77 91 8 product: 33633600 max: 218618400

49 49 99 40 17 product: 161635320 max: 218618400
49 99 40 17 81 product: 267193080 max: 267193080
99 40 17 81 18 product: 98152560 max: 267193080
40 17 81 18 57 product: 56512080 max: 267193080
17 81 18 57 60 product: 84768120 max: 267193080
81 18 57 60 87 product: 433813320 max: 433813320
18 57 60 87 17 product: 91047240 max: 433813320
57 60 87 17 40 product: 202327200 max: 433813320
60 87 17 40 98 product: 347860800 max: 433813320
87 17 40 98 43 product: 249300240 max: 433813320
17 40 98 43 69 product: 197720880 max: 433813320
40 98 43 69 48 product: 558270720 max: 558270720
98 43 69 48 4 product: 55827072 max: 558270720
43 69 48 4 56 product: 31901184 max: 558270720
69 48 4 56 62 product: 45997056 max: 558270720
48 4 56 62 0 product: 0 max: 558270720

81 49 31 73 55 product: 494001585 max: 558270720
49 31 73 55 79 product: 481804015 max: 558270720
31 73 55 79 14 product: 137658290 max: 558270720
73 55 79 14 29 product: 128777110 max: 558270720
55 79 14 29 93 product: 164058510 max: 558270720
79 14 29 93 71 product: 211784622 max: 558270720
14 29 93 71 40 product: 107232720 max: 558270720
29 93 71 40 67 product: 513185160 max: 558270720
93 71 40 67 53 product: 937890120 max: 937890120
71 40 67 53 88 product: 887465920 max: 937890120
40 67 53 88 30 product: 374985600 max: 937890120
67 53 88 30 3 product: 28123920 max: 937890120
53 88 30 3 49 product: 20568240 max: 937890120
88 30 3 49 13 product: 5045040 max: 937890120
30 3 49 13 36 product: 2063880 max: 937890120
3 49 13 36 65 product: 4471740 max: 937890120

52 70 95 23 4 product: 31813600 max: 937890120
70 95 23 4 60 product: 36708000 max: 937890120
95 23 4 60 11 product: 5768400 max: 937890120
23 4 60 11 42 product: 2550240 max: 937890120
4 60 11 42 69 product: 7650720 max: 937890120
60 11 42 69 24 product: 45904320 max: 937890120
11 42 69 24 68 product: 52024896 max: 937890120
42 69 24 68 56 product: 264854016 max: 937890120
69 24 68 56 1 product: 6306048 max: 937890120
24 68 56 1 32 product: 2924544 max: 937890120
68 56 1 32 56 product: 6823936 max: 937890120
56 1 32 56 71 product: 7124992 max: 937890120
1 32 56 71 37 product: 4707584 max: 937890120
32 56 71 37 2 product: 9415168 max: 937890120
56 71 37 2 36 product: 10592064 max: 937890120
71 37 2 36 91 product: 17212104 max: 937890120

22 31 16 71 51 product: 39512352 max: 937890120
31 16 71 51 67 product: 120333072 max: 937890120
16 71 51 67 63 product: 244547856 max: 937890120
71 51 67 63 89 product: 1360297449 max: 1360297449
51 67 63 89 41 product: 785523879 max: 1360297449
67 63 89 41 92 product: 1417023468 max: 1417023468
63 89 41 92 36 product: 761385744 max: 1417023468
89 41 92 36 54 product: 652616352 max: 1417023468
41 92 36 54 22 product: 161320896 max: 1417023468
92 36 54 22 40 product: 157386240 max: 1417023468
36 54 22 40 40 product: 68428800 max: 1417023468
54 22 40 40 28 product: 53222400 max: 1417023468
22 40 40 28 66 product: 65049600 max: 1417023468
40 40 28 66 33 product: 97574400 max: 1417023468
40 28 66 33 13 product: 31711680 max: 1417023468
28 66 33 13 80 product: 63423360 max: 1417023468

24 47 32 60 99 product: 214410240 max: 1417023468
47 32 60 99 3 product: 26801280 max: 1417023468
32 60 99 3 45 product: 25660800 max: 1417023468
60 99 3 45 2 product: 1603800 max: 1417023468
99 3 45 2 44 product: 1176120 max: 1417023468
3 45 2 44 75 product: 891000 max: 1417023468
45 2 44 75 33 product: 9801000 max: 1417023468
2 44 75 33 53 product: 11543400 max: 1417023468
44 75 33 53 78 product: 450192600 max: 1417023468
75 33 53 78 36 product: 368339400 max: 1417023468
33 53 78 36 84 product: 412540128 max: 1417023468
53 78 36 84 20 product: 250024320 max: 1417023468
78 36 84 20 35 product: 165110400 max: 1417023468
36 84 20 35 17 product: 35985600 max: 1417023468
84 20 35 17 12 product: 11995200 max: 1417023468
20 35 17 12 50 product: 7140000 max: 1417023468

32 98 81 28 64 product: 455196672 max: 1417023468
98 81 28 64 23 product: 327172608 max: 1417023468
81 28 64 23 67 product: 223679232 max: 1417023468
28 64 23 67 10 product: 27614720 max: 1417023468
64 23 67 10 26 product: 25642240 max: 1417023468
23 67 10 26 38 product: 15225080 max: 1417023468
67 10 26 38 40 product: 26478400 max: 1417023468
10 26 38 40 67 product: 26478400 max: 1417023468
26 38 40 67 59 product: 156222560 max: 1417023468
38 40 67 59 54 product: 324462240 max: 1417023468
40 67 59 54 70 product: 597693600 max: 1417023468
67 59 54 70 66 product: 986194440 max: 1417023468
59 54 70 66 18 product: 264947760 max: 1417023468
54 70 66 18 38 product: 170644320 max: 1417023468
70 66 18 38 64 product: 202245120 max: 1417023468
66 18 38 64 70 product: 202245120 max: 1417023468

67 26 20 68 2 product: 4738240 max: 1417023468
26 20 68 2 62 product: 4384640 max: 1417023468
20 68 2 62 12 product: 2023680 max: 1417023468
68 2 62 12 20 product: 2023680 max: 1417023468
2 62 12 20 95 product: 2827200 max: 1417023468
62 12 20 95 63 product: 89056800 max: 1417023468
12 20 95 63 94 product: 135021600 max: 1417023468
20 95 63 94 39 product: 438820200 max: 1417023468
95 63 94 39 63 product: 1382283630 max: 1417023468
63 94 39 63 8 product: 116402832 max: 1417023468
94 39 63 8 40 product: 73906560 max: 1417023468
39 63 8 40 91 product: 71547840 max: 1417023468
63 8 40 91 66 product: 121080960 max: 1417023468
8 40 91 66 49 product: 94174080 max: 1417023468
40 91 66 49 94 product: 1106545440 max: 1417023468
91 66 49 94 21 product: 580936356 max: 1417023468

24 55 58 5 66 product: 25264800 max: 1417023468
55 58 5 66 73 product: 76847100 max: 1417023468
58 5 66 73 99 product: 138324780 max: 1417023468
5 66 73 99 26 product: 62007660 max: 1417023468
66 73 99 26 97 product: 1202948604 max: 1417023468
73 99 26 97 17 product: 309850398 max: 1417023468
99 26 97 17 78 product: 331073028 max: 1417023468
26 97 17 78 78 product: 260845416 max: 1417023468
97 17 78 78 96 product: 963121536 max: 1417023468
17 78 78 96 83 product: 824114304 max: 1417023468
78 78 96 83 14 product: 678682368 max: 1417023468
78 96 83 14 88 product: 765692928 max: 1417023468
96 83 14 88 34 product: 333763584 max: 1417023468
83 14 88 34 89 product: 309426656 max: 1417023468
14 88 34 89 63 product: 234866016 max: 1417023468
88 34 89 63 72 product: 1207882368 max: 1417023468

21 36 23 9 75 product: 11736900 max: 1417023468
36 23 9 75 0 product: 0 max: 1417023468
23 9 75 0 76 product: 0 max: 1417023468
9 75 0 76 44 product: 0 max: 1417023468
75 0 76 44 20 product: 0 max: 1417023468
0 76 44 20 45 product: 0 max: 1417023468
76 44 20 45 35 product: 105336000 max: 1417023468
44 20 45 35 14 product: 19404000 max: 1417023468
20 45 35 14 0 product: 0 max: 1417023468
45 35 14 0 61 product: 0 max: 1417023468
35 14 0 61 33 product: 0 max: 1417023468
14 0 61 33 97 product: 0 max: 1417023468
0 61 33 97 34 product: 0 max: 1417023468
61 33 97 34 31 product: 205805094 max: 1417023468
33 97 34 31 33 product: 111337182 max: 1417023468
97 34 31 33 95 product: 320516130 max: 1417023468

78 17 53 28 22 product: 43291248 max: 1417023468
17 53 28 22 75 product: 41626200 max: 1417023468
53 28 22 75 31 product: 75906600 max: 1417023468
28 22 75 31 67 product: 95957400 max: 1417023468
22 75 31 67 15 product: 51405750 max: 1417023468
75 31 67 15 94 product: 219642750 max: 1417023468
31 67 15 94 3 product: 8785710 max: 1417023468
67 15 94 3 80 product: 22672800 max: 1417023468
15 94 3 80 4 product: 1353600 max: 1417023468
94 3 80 4 62 product: 5594880 max: 1417023468
3 80 4 62 16 product: 952320 max: 1417023468
80 4 62 16 14 product: 4444160 max: 1417023468
4 62 16 14 9 product: 499968 max: 1417023468
62 16 14 9 53 product: 6624576 max: 1417023468
16 14 9 53 56 product: 5983488 max: 1417023468
14 9 53 56 92 product: 34405056 max: 1417023468

16 39 5 42 96 product: 12579840 max: 1417023468
39 5 42 96 35 product: 27518400 max: 1417023468
5 42 96 35 31 product: 21873600 max: 1417023468
42 96 35 31 47 product: 205611840 max: 1417023468
96 35 31 47 55 product: 269253600 max: 1417023468
35 31 47 55 58 product: 162674050 max: 1417023468
31 47 55 58 88 product: 409009040 max: 1417023468
47 55 58 88 24 product: 316652160 max: 1417023468
55 58 88 24 0 product: 0 max: 1417023468
58 88 24 0 17 product: 0 max: 1417023468
88 24 0 17 54 product: 0 max: 1417023468
24 0 17 54 24 product: 0 max: 1417023468
0 17 54 24 36 product: 0 max: 1417023468
17 54 24 36 29 product: 23001408 max: 1417023468
54 24 36 29 85 product: 115007040 max: 1417023468
24 36 29 85 57 product: 121396320 max: 1417023468

86 56 0 48 35 product: 0 max: 1417023468
56 0 48 35 71 product: 0 max: 1417023468
0 48 35 71 89 product: 0 max: 1417023468
48 35 71 89 7 product: 74311440 max: 1417023468
35 71 89 7 5 product: 7740775 max: 1417023468
71 89 7 5 44 product: 9731260 max: 1417023468
89 7 5 44 44 product: 6030640 max: 1417023468
7 5 44 44 37 product: 2507120 max: 1417023468
5 44 44 37 44 product: 15759040 max: 1417023468
44 44 37 44 60 product: 189108480 max: 1417023468
44 37 44 60 21 product: 90256320 max: 1417023468
37 44 60 21 58 product: 118974240 max: 1417023468
44 60 21 58 51 product: 163991520 max: 1417023468
60 21 58 51 54 product: 201262320 max: 1417023468
21 58 51 54 17 product: 57024324 max: 1417023468
58 51 54 17 58 product: 157495752 max: 1417023468

19 80 81 68 5 product: 41860800 max: 1417023468
80 81 68 5 94 product: 207100800 max: 1417023468
81 68 5 94 47 product: 121671720 max: 1417023468
68 5 94 47 69 product: 103646280 max: 1417023468
5 94 47 69 28 product: 42677880 max: 1417023468
94 47 69 28 73 product: 623097048 max: 1417023468
47 69 28 73 92 product: 609839664 max: 1417023468
69 28 73 92 13 product: 168679056 max: 1417023468
28 73 92 13 86 product: 210237664 max: 1417023468
73 92 13 86 52 product: 390441376 max: 1417023468
92 13 86 52 17 product: 90924704 max: 1417023468
13 86 52 17 77 product: 76100024 max: 1417023468
86 52 17 77 4 product: 23415392 max: 1417023468
52 17 77 4 89 product: 24232208 max: 1417023468
17 77 4 89 55 product: 25630220 max: 1417023468
77 4 89 55 40 product: 60306400 max: 1417023468

4 52 8 83 97 product: 13396864 max: 1417023468
52 8 83 97 35 product: 117222560 max: 1417023468
8 83 97 35 99 product: 223173720 max: 1417023468
83 97 35 99 16 product: 446347440 max: 1417023468
97 35 99 16 7 product: 37643760 max: 1417023468
35 99 16 7 97 product: 37643760 max: 1417023468
99 16 7 97 57 product: 61305552 max: 1417023468
16 7 97 57 32 product: 19815936 max: 1417023468
7 97 57 32 16 product: 19815936 max: 1417023468
97 57 32 16 26 product: 73602048 max: 1417023468
57 32 16 26 26 product: 19728384 max: 1417023468
32 16 26 26 79 product: 27342848 max: 1417023468
16 26 26 79 33 product: 28197312 max: 1417023468
26 26 79 33 27 product: 47582964 max: 1417023468
26 79 33 27 98 product: 179351172 max: 1417023468
79 33 27 98 66 product: 455276052 max: 1417023468

88 36 68 87 57 product: 1068287616 max: 1417023468
36 68 87 57 62 product: 752657184 max: 1417023468
68 87 57 62 20 product: 418142880 max: 1417023468
87 57 62 20 72 product: 442739520 max: 1417023468
57 62 20 72 3 product: 15266880 max: 1417023468
62 20 72 3 46 product: 12320640 max: 1417023468
20 72 3 46 33 product: 6557760 max: 1417023468
72 3 46 33 67 product: 21968496 max: 1417023468
3 46 33 67 46 product: 14035428 max: 1417023468
46 33 67 46 55 product: 257316180 max: 1417023468
33 67 46 55 12 product: 67125960 max: 1417023468
67 46 55 12 32 product: 65091840 max: 1417023468
46 55 12 32 63 product: 61205760 max: 1417023468
55 12 32 63 93 product: 123742080 max: 1417023468
12 32 63 93 53 product: 119242368 max: 1417023468
32 63 93 53 69 product: 685643616 max: 1417023468

4 42 16 73 38 product: 7456512 max: 1417023468
42 16 73 38 25 product: 46603200 max: 1417023468
16 73 38 25 39 product: 43274400 max: 1417023468
73 38 25 39 11 product: 29751150 max: 1417023468
38 25 39 11 24 product: 9781200 max: 1417023468
25 39 11 24 94 product: 24195600 max: 1417023468
39 11 24 94 72 product: 69683328 max: 1417023468
11 24 94 72 18 product: 32161536 max: 1417023468
24 94 72 18 8 product: 23390208 max: 1417023468
94 72 18 8 46 product: 44831232 max: 1417023468
72 18 8 46 29 product: 13830912 max: 1417023468
18 8 46 29 32 product: 6147072 max: 1417023468
8 46 29 32 40 product: 13660160 max: 1417023468
46 29 32 40 62 product: 105866240 max: 1417023468
29 32 40 62 76 product: 174909440 max: 1417023468
32 40 62 76 36 product: 217128960 max: 1417023468

20 69 36 41 72 product: 146655360 max: 1417023468
69 36 41 72 30 product: 219983040 max: 1417023468
36 41 72 30 23 product: 73327680 max: 1417023468
41 72 30 23 88 product: 179245440 max: 1417023468
72 30 23 88 34 product: 148642560 max: 1417023468
30 23 88 34 62 product: 127997760 max: 1417023468
23 88 34 62 99 product: 422392608 max: 1417023468
88 34 62 99 69 product: 1267177824 max: 1417023468
34 62 99 69 82 product: 1180779336 max: 1417023468
62 99 69 82 67 product: -1968137428 max: 1417023468   //ISSUE HERE
99 69 82 67 59 product: -2080725970 max: 1417023468   //ISSUE HERE
69 82 67 59 85 product: 1901116290 max: 1901116290
82 67 59 85 74 product: 2038878340 max: 2038878340
67 59 85 74 4 product: 99457480 max: 2038878340
59 85 74 4 36 product: 53439840 max: 2038878340
85 74 4 36 16 product: 14492160 max: 2038878340

20 73 35 29 78 product: 115588200 max: 2038878340
73 35 29 78 31 product: 179161710 max: 2038878340
35 29 78 31 90 product: 220884300 max: 2038878340
29 78 31 90 1 product: 6310980 max: 2038878340
78 31 90 1 74 product: 16103880 max: 2038878340
31 90 1 74 31 product: 6400260 max: 2038878340
90 1 74 31 49 product: 10116540 max: 2038878340
1 74 31 49 71 product: 7980826 max: 2038878340
74 31 49 71 48 product: 383079648 max: 2038878340
31 49 71 48 86 product: 445200672 max: 2038878340
49 71 48 86 81 product: 1163266272 max: 2038878340
71 48 86 81 16 product: 379842048 max: 2038878340
48 86 81 16 23 product: 123047424 max: 2038878340
86 81 16 23 57 product: 146118816 max: 2038878340
81 16 23 57 5 product: 8495280 max: 2038878340
16 23 57 5 54 product: 5663520 max: 2038878340

1 70 54 71 83 product: 22275540 max: 2038878340
70 54 71 83 51 product: 1136052540 max: 2038878340
54 71 83 51 54 product: 876383388 max: 2038878340
71 83 51 54 69 product: 1119823218 max: 2038878340
83 51 54 69 16 product: 252354528 max: 2038878340
51 54 69 16 92 product: 279718272 max: 2038878340
54 69 16 92 33 product: 180994176 max: 2038878340
69 16 92 33 48 product: 160883712 max: 2038878340
16 92 33 48 61 product: 142230528 max: 2038878340
92 33 48 61 43 product: 382244544 max: 2038878340
33 48 61 43 52 product: 216051264 max: 2038878340
48 61 43 52 1 product: 6547008 max: 2038878340
61 43 52 1 89 product: 12139244 max: 2038878340
43 52 1 89 19 product: 3781076 max: 2038878340
52 1 89 19 67 product: 5891444 max: 2038878340
1 89 19 67 48 product: 5438256 max: 2038878340

The max is: 2038878340
```

Comment: You should double-check the problem description. The way you are trying to solve the problem should not overflow. However, you have missed one important detail so that you are answering a slightly different question.

Comment: Many answers below are correct.  You are overflowing `int` and should be using `long long` or `uint64_t` for all values within the matrix and resulting products.

Comment: @all: thank you for your responses, this is my first time to visit this site. I learned two things today: 1) Read the problem carefully 2) don't forget about casting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your product calculation is done at `int` precision and then stored into `long long`. You need to do the calculation at `long long` precision.

```
long long hZ_product = 1;
hZ_product *= matrix[i][j];
hZ_product *= matrix[i][j+1];
hZ_product *= matrix[i][j+2];
hZ_product *= matrix[i][j+3];
hZ_product *= matrix[i][j+4];
```

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
hZ_product = (matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j+1] * matrix[i][j+2] * matrix[i][j+3] * matrix[i][j+4]);
```

you are multiplying a bunch of integer values together and *then* assigning the result to a `long long hZ_product`.  That is causing integer overflow.

Try casting each operand in the multiplication to *long long* to avoid the overflow.

Answer (score 2):

A correct solution to this problem doesn't overflow an `int`. Read the problem description more closely, it wants "the greatest product of **four** adjacent numbers". The contents of the grid are two-digit numbers so the maximum possible value is 99^4 or 96059601. This fits comfortably in a 32-bit `int`. You shouldn't be multiplying *five* grid cells together when the problem only asks for *four* adjacent numbers. Once you've fixed that you still need to check all directions (horizontal, vertical, and diagonal). Keep working on it and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing the 4-byte integer.

First of all, I would like to say that project euler wants you to multiply 4 integers. You multiplied 5 integers. If you only multipled 4 integers, you would not overflow.

Assuming you want to multiply 5 integers, this line doesn't cast to long long until the product is calculated.

```
hZ_product = (matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j+1] * matrix[i][j+2] * matrix[i][j+3] * matrix[i][j+4]);
```

By which time it is too late, it has already overflowed.

The easiest way to fix this is:

```
hZ_product = (long long)matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j+1] * matrix[i][j+2] * matrix[i][j+3] * matrix[i][j+4];
```

This casts the first integer to long long. The rest will cast/promote automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ everyone for your help.

Here is the final code I came up with which worked. I'm sure it's possible to make it a bit more efficient like not running 4 separate for-loops to check horizontal, vertical, diagonal left, and diagonal right products but I couldn't figure out how to internally customize each for iteration parameters to achieve this. Additionally, as I wrote the code I realized that writing four functions really wasn't necessary because I ended up having 4 different for loops, and in the end writing functions didn't make the code any more simple and seeing how this is a Project Euler problem, maintainability isn't really a consideration. I'm obviously not a very experienced programmer so I feel like I make mistakes at every turn. Are there any glaring inefficiencies in my final product?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int hZ (int matrix[20][20], int i, int j);
int vZ (int matrix[20][20], int i, int j);
int dZ_right (int matrix[20][20], int i, int j);
int dZ_left (int matrix[20][20], int i, int j);

int main()
{
    fstream inFile;
    int matrix [20][20];
    int hZ_max, vZ_max, dZ_right_max, dZ_left_max = 0;
    inFile.open("numbers.txt");
    if(!inFile)
        cout << "numbers.txt failed to open!" << endl;

    //Populates the array with data

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            inFile >> matrix[i][j];

    //Horizontal Analysis

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
        {
            int hZ_temp = hZ(matrix, i, j);
            if (hZ_temp > hZ_max)
            {
                hZ_max = hZ_temp;
                cout << "hZ: " << matrix[i][j] << " " << matrix[i][j+1] << " " << matrix[i][j+2] << " " << matrix [i][j+3] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    //Vertical Analysis

    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                int vZ_temp = vZ(matrix, i, j);
                if (vZ_temp > vZ_max)
                {
                    vZ_max = vZ_temp;
                    cout << "vZ: " << matrix[i][j] << " " << matrix[i+1][j] << " " << matrix[i+2][j] << " " << matrix [i+3][j] << endl;
                }
            }
        }

    //Right Diagonal Analysis

    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
        {
            int dZ_right_temp = dZ_right(matrix, i, j);
                if (dZ_right_temp > dZ_right_max)
                {
                    dZ_right_max = dZ_right_temp;
                    cout << "dZ_right: " << matrix[i][j] << " " << matrix[i+1][j+1] << " " << matrix[i+2][j+2] << " " << matrix [i+3][j+3] << endl;
                }
        }
    }

    //Left Diagonal Analysis

    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 3; j < 17; j++ )
        {
            int dZ_left_temp = dZ_left(matrix, i, j);
                if(dZ_left_temp > dZ_left_max)
                {
                    dZ_left_max = dZ_left_temp;
                    cout << "dZ_left: "<< matrix[i][j] << " " << matrix[i+1][j-1] << " " << matrix[i+2][j-2] << " " << matrix [i+3][j-3] << endl;
                }
        }
    }

    cout << "The max horizontal product is: " << hZ_max << endl;
    cout << "The max vertical product is: " << vZ_max << endl;
    cout << "The max right diagonal product is: " << dZ_right_max << endl;
    cout << "The max left diagonal product is: " << dZ_left_max << endl;

    return 0;
}

//Horizontal Analysis function

int hZ (int matrix[20][20], int i , int j)
{
        int hZ_product = 0;
        hZ_product = matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j+1] * matrix[i][j+2] * matrix[i][j+3];

    return hZ_product;
}

//Vertical Analysis function

int vZ (int matrix[20][20], int i , int j)
{
        int vZ_product = 0;
        vZ_product = matrix[i][j] * matrix[i+1][j] * matrix[i+2][j] * matrix[i+3][j];

    return vZ_product;
}

//Right Diagonal function

int dZ_right (int matrix[20][20], int i , int j)
{
        int dZ_right_product = 0;
        dZ_right_product = matrix[i][j] * matrix[i+1][j+1] * matrix[i+2][j+2] * matrix[i+3][j+3];

    return dZ_right_product;
}

//Left Diagonal function

int dZ_left (int matrix[20][20], int i, int j)
{
    int dZ_left_product = 0;
    dZ_left_product = matrix[i][j] * matrix[i+1][j-1] * matrix[i+2][j-2] * matrix [i+3][j-3];

    return dZ_left_product;
}
```